# Angularjs templateUrl vs template scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I ran into a strange behaviour on angular.
when creating a directive if i use

```
 mod.directive('test', [function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: '/test/test.html',
         transclude: true,
         controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
             //$scope equals containing scope of directive. why???
         }]
     };
 }]);
```

$scope is the same scope (not inherited) as containing scope of directive.

but if i create directive as

```
 mod.directive('test', [function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: '<div><div ng-transclude /></div>',
         transclude: true,
         controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
             //$scope is new. inherited from container scope
         }]
     };
 }]);
```

only difference is template vs templateUrl. "templateUrl" one uses parent scope but "template" one creates a new scope. i dont understand why. could this be an angular bug?

thanks already

Edit: i am using Angular 1.3.0-beta.7

Big-Edit: i am using another directive on same element as @estus mentioned.

```
<test other-directive></test>
```

other-directive is defined as scope:true. but it doesn't create a new scope when used with templateUrl on test directive.

Edit: Sample plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Kghah1rvwFE6TSw85Cog?p=preview (templateUrl)

plnkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/Axiye1ksBMR8dp9ND8tL?p=preview (template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is confusing but [expected behaviour](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-) for a directive with asynchronously loaded template (via `templateUrl`):

> Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend
>   compilation of directives on that element for later when the template
>   has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and
>   link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not
>   contained any directives.

To get around this issue use `priority` to compile the directive with new scope in the first place:

```
app.directive('directiveOne', function () {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'directive-template.html',
         transclude: true,
         controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
         ...
         }]
     };
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function () {
     return {
         priority: 100,
         scope: true
    };
});
```

Comment: yeah there is another directive on same element. see edited question pls

Comment: Updated the answer. What did make you think that the directive with templateUrl doesn't have a new scope?

Comment: i'll post a working plunkr tomorrow at office. my codes arent with me now.

Comment: i added plnkr to question

Comment: I see. Yes, cached templates aren't illustrative here, because when the directive is being compiled the first time, its template will be loaded asynchronously. I've updated the answer to match the question.

Comment: so, when angular sees a directive with templateUrl it continues to compile sibling directives. Does it assume my directive with templateUrl could have scope:true so it doesn't create a new scope for it's sibling?

Comment: As for the siblings, notice that the manual talks about 'sibling elements', for the single element (the one that has directiveOne and directiveTwo) directiveOne will be compiled before directiveTwo. Sure, you can have `scope:true` in both of them, it will make their behaviour less ambiguous.

Comment: sorry for taking your time and thanks for effort. i understood how it works but i dont understand why it works like this. why doesn't angular create a new scope for sibling directive while loading async template? by the way i assume directive-two is sibling to directive-one or am i wrong? <directive-one directive-two></directive-one>